# Need to save a copy in my own location in old Excel format

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\Group \Shared Services\Accounts\" _
    & "UPLOAD - " & Format(Range("T1"), "dd-mm-yyyy"), FileFormat:=56
```

I need to save this in the same location as current file instead of saving at a given location.
It is really important to use `FileFormat:=56` as this need to upload to a connector.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: I need to save in the same location as mine current file. Just sort-out a method.

Comment: Oh ok. I see you got your answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path _ 
    & "\UPLOAD - " & Format(Range("T1"), "dd-mm-yyyy") & " ", 56
```

51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)

Comment: I answered my own question as it worked here...
Even L42 accept it. I don't know what you mean by the above comment Hemang.

Comment: Ok, I'm not aware of this language, if this answer really satisfy the future readers needs then I'm sorry, let me know and I'll delete my comments. But if you can update it little with more details and can explain how you able to solve it, then it'll increase the quality of the answer, bet with me, people like well explained answer. :)